# Green's function for $2^\text{nd}$ order PDE

Tags: partial-differential-equations, differential-operators, greens-function

Has anyone an idea how to find the Green's function of the operator 
$$
\widehat{{\mathcal{O}}}=-\frac{1}{R} \partial_z^2 - \partial_R \frac{1}{R} \partial_R?
$$

**UPDATE1:** For my own record (and anyone else who is interested) here is what one may call a solution or the way how I found it. I was first looking for solutions of the homogenous equation using a separation ansatz $f_R(R)f_z(z)$. The general solution then found this way is
$$
G(R,z) = \int_{0}^\infty c_k \, R \, J_1\left(kR\right) \, e^{-k|z|} \, {\rm d}k
$$
because it should be invariant as $z\rightarrow -z$.
I'm not quite sure why one has to discard the second solution $Y_1$ as $R Y_1$ is finite at the origin. However it does not seem to yield the correct result as the integral over the surface after using Gauss theorem seems to give a zero result as the integrand is odd.

In analogy to the cylindrical laplacian whose Greens function $G\sim \frac{1}{\sqrt{R^2 + z^2}}$ can be found as a linear combination $\int_{0}^\infty J_0\left(kR\right) e^{-k|z|} \, {\rm d}k$ I expected to get the solution by plugging in $c_k=c$ where c is a dimensionless constant. Note that $\widehat{\cal O}$ has dimension $L^{-3}$ and therefore $$\widehat{\cal O} G = \frac{\delta(R)\delta(\varphi)\delta(z)}{R}$$ should be dimensionless when integrated over the entire volume. This implies that $G$ should be dimensionless too. Assuming $c_k$ does not depend on any other hidden parameters and $k$ has dimension $L^{-1}$ the only viable combination is $c_k=c$ being a dimensionless constant.

The solution of the integral then is $$G(R,z) = c\left(1-\frac{|z|}{\sqrt{R^2+z^2}}\right)$$. However as a Greens function should vanish at $\infty$ this result can not be quite right, because it does vanish as $|z| \rightarrow \infty$, but not as $R \rightarrow \infty$. Discarding the first constant term (which is irrelevant for the PDE) gives the opposite discrepancy: It vanishes as $R \rightarrow \infty$, but not as $|z| \rightarrow \infty$. This combined with the fact, that $$\int_V \underbrace{\widehat{\cal O} G}_{\equiv \, {\rm div} \vec{F}} \, {\rm d}V = \int_A \vec{F}\cdot {\rm d}\vec{A}$$ depends on the precise integration region $(\sim \ln (zR))$ led me to conclusion that probably this operator does not have a Greens function. Does anyone know if there is an existence theorem to any arbitrary Operator? Has it something to do with a PDE of second order has to have dimension $L^{-2}$ ?? See below:

Since in my case I want to solve the equation $\widehat{\cal O}\Psi(R,z) = \omega_{\varphi}(R,z)$ this is equivalent to solving $R\widehat{\cal O}\Psi(R,z) = R\,\omega_{\varphi}(R,z)$ and therefore I'm looking for a Greensfunction $G$ to the operator $R{\widehat{\cal O}}$ which has dimension $L^{-2}$ same as for the laplacian. Thus the Greensfunction $G(R,z)$ as the $\frac{1}{r}$ solution to the laplacian has to have dimension $L^{-1}$. Following the argument similar to above I conclude $c_k=ck$ again with a dimensionless constant $c$ and therefore $$G(R,z)=\frac{c\,R^2}{\left(R^2+z^2\right)^{\frac{3}{2}}}$$. This function now indeed has all the properties it needs to have and in particular $$\int_V \underbrace{R\widehat{\cal O} G}_{\equiv \, {\rm div} \vec{F}} \, {\rm d}V = \int_A \vec{F}\cdot {\rm d}\vec{A}$$ is independent on the integration region!

By choosing the tube of radius $R>0$ from $z=-\infty..\infty$ I readily obtain $$\int_A \vec{F}\cdot {\rm d}\vec{A} = 2\pi \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} R F_R(R,z) \, {\rm d}z = 8\pi c \stackrel{!}{=} 1$$ fixing $c$.

$F_R$ is determined by the equation $$\frac{1}{R} \partial_R R F_R = -R\partial_R \frac{1}{R} \partial_R G = \partial_z^2 G$$ i.e.
$$
RF_R(R,z) - R_0F_R(R_0,z) = \int_{R_0}^{R} R' \, \partial_z^2 G(R',z) \, {\rm d}R' \\
\Longrightarrow \qquad F_R(R,z) = \frac{3cR^3}{\left(R^2 + z^2\right)^{\frac{5}{2}}}
$$.

**UPDATE2:** In continuing I noticed that above function is not really good when it comes to finding an inhomogenous solution since that would need to be of the form
$$
\Psi(R,z) = \int_V {\rm d}V' \, G\left(R,z,R',z'\right) \, R'\omega_{\varphi}\left(R',z'\right)
$$
but $G(R-R',z-z')$ from above is not a solution to the Operator $R\widehat{\cal O}$. :-(

${\rm d}V'$ is an appropriate Volume element (not nececarily the cylinder or??)

In which cases can this function be found just by replacing $R \rightarrow R- R'$ and $z \rightarrow z-z'$ ???

So I'm basically starting all over again and this time I try to construct it as
$$
G(R,z,R',z') = \int_{0}^\infty c_k \, RJ_1\left(kR\right) \, R'J_1\left(kR'\right) \, e^{-k|z-z'|} \, {\rm d}k
$$
The idea now is to choose $c_k$ such that the integral over the parameterspace $(R',z')$ with Gauss-Theorem yields a result independent on $(R,z)$. I'm not sure though (as hinted above) if I need to consider in fact a full cylindrical geometry such that
$$
R\widehat{\cal O} \, G = \frac{\delta(R-R') \delta(z-z') \delta(\phi-\phi')}{R}
$$
with physical meaning or if any Greensfunction in an arbitrary parameterspace will suffice i.e. choosing the following equation
$$
R\widehat{\cal O} \, G = \delta(R-R') \delta(z-z') \tag{0}
$$
so that $G$ now is dimensionless ($R\widehat{\cal O}$ has dimension $L^{-2}$ as does the RHS). If I try to construct it using the latter equation, then since $G$ is dimensionless the most simple ansatz (with powers of $k$) must be $c_k=ck$ ($k$ has dimension $L^{-1}$) again with $c$ a dimensionless constant.
The integral is actually calculatable by the formula
$$
\int_{0}^\infty e^{-kz} \, J_\mu(kR) \, J_\mu(kR') \, {\rm d}k = \frac{1}{\pi \sqrt{RR'}} \, Q_{\mu-\frac{1}{2}} \left( \frac{z^2 + R^2 + R'^2}{2RR'} \right)
$$
The additional $k$ in the integrand is obtained by deriving with respect to $z$. However things are getting rather complicated so I will stay with the integral to calculate the flux through the surface.
In a 2d cartesian coordinate system I will take $R'$ as x-coordinate and $z'$ as y.
The only way I could solve the Flux through the surfaces was to choose the boundary as the line (from $R'=0..\infty$) at $z'=z+\epsilon$ and $z'=z-\epsilon$ parallel to the R' axis, and the line from $z'=z-\epsilon$ to $z'=z+\epsilon$ at $R'=0$ and $R'=\infty$ respectively. Thus we need
$$
F_{z'} = - \partial_{z'} G = -\int_{0}^\infty c k \begin{cases} -k \quad &z'>z \\ k \quad &z'<z \end{cases} \bigg\} \, RJ_1\left(kR\right) \, R'J_1\left(kR'\right) \, e^{-k|z-z'|} \, {\rm d}k
$$
and the flux through the boundary at $z'=z\pm\epsilon$ (in $\pm z'$-direction) is
$$
\int_{z'=z\pm\epsilon} \vec{F}\cdot {\rm d}\vec{A} = \int_{0}^\infty {\rm d}R' \, \left( F_{z+\epsilon} - F_{z-\epsilon} \right)
$$
The integral over $R'$ gives a factor of $\frac{2}{k^2}$ and thus
$$
\int_{z'=z\pm\epsilon} \vec{F}\cdot {\rm d}\vec{A} = 2c \int_{0}^\infty RJ_1\left(kR\right) \, e^{-k|z-z'|} \, {\rm d}k \stackrel{|z-z'|=\epsilon}{=} 2c\left(1-\frac{\epsilon}{\sqrt{\epsilon^2 + R^2}}\right) \tag{1}
$$

The integral over the surface in positive $R'-$direction (from $z'=z-\epsilon..z+\epsilon$) needs
$$ F_{R'} - F_{R'_0} = -\int_{R'_0}^{R'} R'' \partial_{R''} \frac{1}{R''} \partial_{R''} G(R,z,R'',z') \, {\rm d}R'' \\ 
= \int_{0}^\infty ck \, RJ_1\left(kR\right) \, e^{-k|z-z'|} \, {\rm d}k \int_{R'_0}^{R'} k^2 R''J_1\left(kR''\right) \, {\rm d}R'' $$
and thus for $R'=\infty$ (boundary at $\infty$) and $R_0'=0$ (arbitrary integration constant)
$$
\int_{z-\epsilon}^{z+\epsilon} F_{R'}(R,z,R'=\infty,z') \, {\rm d}z' \\
= \int_{z-\epsilon}^{z+\epsilon} F_{0}(R,z,0,z') \, {\rm d}z' + \int_{0}^\infty 2c \, RJ_1\left(kR\right) \, \left[ 1 - e^{-k\epsilon} \right] \, {\rm d}k \underbrace{\int_{0}^{\infty} k^2 R''J_1\left(kR''\right) \, {\rm d}R''}_{=1} \\
= \int_{z-\epsilon}^{z+\epsilon} F_{0}(R,z,0,z') \, {\rm d}z' + \frac{2c\epsilon}{\sqrt{\epsilon^2+R^2}}. \tag{2}$$

Conversely the opposite part in negative $R'$-direction at $R'=0$ gives
$$-\int_{z-\epsilon}^{z+\epsilon} F_{0}(R,z,0,z') \, {\rm d}z' \tag{3}$$
and therefore after adding up all the parts $(1)+(2)+(3)$ we have
$$
\int_{\text{boundary}} \vec{F} \cdot {\rm d}\vec{A} = 2c \stackrel{!}{=} 1
$$
independent of $R,z$ and $\epsilon$, implying $c=\frac{1}{2}$. Hence, $$G(R,z,R',z')=-\frac{\sqrt{RR'}}{2\pi} \, \frac{{\rm d}}{{\rm d}t} Q_{\frac{1}{2}} \left( \frac{t^2 + R^2 + R'^2}{2RR'} \right)\Bigg|_{t=|z-z'|}$$ is a Greens-function satisfying (0).

Comment: What does the -3 on the left mean?

Comment: It means people dislike your questions. It would help to include more context, i.e your motivation, where this problem came from, and your attempts to solve it.

Comment: When trying to solve the viscous equation $\nabla p = - \nabla \times \vec{\omega}$ for cylindrical coordinates in a tube it arises in terms of an inhomogenous equation for the streamfunction $\Psi$ and the inhomogeneity $\omega_\varphi$ which is known.
The equation then sounds $\widehat{{\mathcal{O}}} \Psi = \omega_\varphi$. Thus I need to find a Greens-function right? What I have so far is from using separation of Variables i.e. $G \sim \int_{0}^\infty {\rm d}k \, e^{-kz} \, R \, J_1(kR) = \frac{\sqrt{R^2+z^2}-z}{\sqrt{R^2+z^2}}$. But is this the Greens function up to normalization?

Comment: When doing the completely analogous procedure for the cylindrical laplacian this would indeed give the Greens-function $G \sim \int_{0}^\infty {\rm d} k \, e^{-kz} \, J_0(kR) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{R^2 + z^2}}$

Comment: However: Being a Greens-function implies that it should have poles somewhere (right?) which the function above doesn't have. It's series abobut z=0 is $1-\frac{z}{R} + {\cal O}(z^3)$ and about R=0 is $\frac{R^2}{2z^2} + {\cal O}(R^4)$. Also I expect the Greens function to solve $\widehat{{\mathcal{O}}}G = \frac{\delta (R) \delta (\varphi) \delta(z) }{R}$ such that $\int_V {\rm d}^3x \, \underbrace{\widehat{{\mathcal{O}}}G}_{\equiv {\rm div} \vec{F}} = \int_A {\rm d}\vec{A} \cdot \vec{F} = c$ where c is a constant.

Comment: Anyway my result depends on R which it should not I guess...

Comment: Actually the above result for the "Greensfunction" doesn't vanish at infinity, so it should. I therefore have to drop the first term which is constant anyhow and am left with $G\sim \frac{z}{\sqrt{R^2+z^2}}$ ?

Put on hold???

Comment: Let me maybe point out the 2 questions hidden in the text:
"Does anyone know if there is an existence theorem (for the Greensfunction) to any arbitrary Operator? Has it something to do with a PDE of second order has to have dimension $L^{-2}$ ?? See below:"

Comment: Can anyone explain what "on hold" meant?

Comment: Read the rules before you post. It's explained [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/asking). Also [How to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question) and [How to ask a homework question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1803/how-to-ask-a-homework-question). Your question has been reopened after you edited to give more context.

Comment: I still do not see how my additional comments did not suffice to give more context to be removed from the queue "on hold". Do I now need to answer the questions myself in order for being removed from the queue?

Comment: No, you need to *edit the question* with the added information. Comments do not count. Read the rules.

Comment: After reading the first comment (which I hadn't seen is from the OP) I spent some time trying to find an equation with $-3$ on the left, curious to see how an integer could look ambiguous to someone.